# Adonisjs - Inheritence (Base / Admin / Front Controllers)

Tags: node.js, inheritance, adonis.js

I am kind of new to Adonisjs framework. I have been developing my first nodejs application using this awesome framework. I have been trying to create an application structure like

- Base
- Admin extends Base
- Front extends Base

For this I tried creating a base class (app/Http/Controllers/BaseController.js) as follows:

```
'use strict'

class BaseController {
    constructor () {

        [...]

    }
}

module.exports = BaseController
```

Admin class (app/Http/Controllers/AdminController.js)

```
'use strict'

const BaseController = use('BaseController')

class AdminController extends BaseController {
    constructor () {

        [...]

    }
}

module.exports = AdminController
```

Front class (app/Http/Controllers/FrontController.js)

```
'use strict'

const BaseController = use('BaseController')

class FrontController extends BaseController {
  constructor () {

        [...]  

  }
}

module.exports = FrontController
```

But I am getting this error `Cannot find module 'BaseController'` at both Admin and Front controllers. I just need a hint / example on how to create a basic inherited class structure in adonisjs framework.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the newest version 4.0 of the framework:

The adonis.js Ioc Container autoloads the contents of the app directory and makes it available under the "App" Namespace (see [Adonis.js 4.0 > Ioc container > Autoloading](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.0/ioc-container#_autoloading)). The exports of the file "app/Http/Controllers/BaseController.js" are therefore available under the name "App/Http/Controllers/BaseController".

So for your example:

```
'use strict'

const BaseController = use('App/Http/Controllers/BaseController') // <--

class AdminController extends BaseController {
    constructor () {
        [...]

    }
}

module.exports = AdminController
```

If you really want to use controllers without a namespace (which i would not recommend) you can introduce a short unique name for them by adding an alias in the "start/app.js" configuration file:

```
...
const aliases = {
  'BaseController': 'App/Http/Controllers/BaseController'
}
...
```

Afterwards you can require the controller class by calling:

```
use('BaseController')
```

**Note:** Don't forget to put `super()` in constructor of child class:

```
constructor () {
    super()
}
```

Comment: Cannot find module 'C:\wamp64\www\trade_findery\site\app/Http/AdminController'

Comment: Never mind. problem solved (path to controller files were wrong) :)